# Python QWebEngineView redirects to wrong language page

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

When I browse to a page using the following code, the result is in another language (Russian I think).  When I browse to the same url in other browsers I get the English 404 page as expected.  I tried setting the accept language, but that didn't help.  What am I missing?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWebEngineView()
w.page().profile().setHttpAcceptLanguage('en')  # This doesn't help
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://turbobit.net/download'))  # Goes to russian? 404 page
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

The following webkit version works as expected

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWebView()
w.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('http://turbobit.net/download'))  # Loads correct English 404 page
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the language before creating the view:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().setHttpAcceptLanguage('en')
w = QWebEngineView()
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://turbobit.net/download'))
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I spent way too much time trying all sorts of stuff to be so close with my initial guess.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: This actually turns out to be a bug in Qt, which will be fixed in 5.9 (or perhaps 5.9.1): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60588